# Ending an activity after a video ends

Tags: android, video, android-activity

Hi I am new to android development and I'm working on a game. Right now I have a cutsceen right now which is a videoview that is called after hitting the start button of the game. I want to be able to be able to end the cutsceen activity immediately after the video ends, but I'm not sure how to do that. At first I tried putting a timer for 25 seconds in onCreate, but that failed since onCreate only happens once. As it is now I have a button to end to the cutsceen, but my question is how do I get the cutsceen activity to end and call the game activity after the video directly ends?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, I'm not really familiar with game development, but I guess it would work the same way. Anyway, is the video in a `VideoView`? If so, you can call [setOnCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29) to it so you will be notified that the video is done playing.

You can then call [finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) on the activity in the callback method.

```
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    finish(); //This will end the current activity
}
```

Comment: Can you let me know how to call an oncomplete listener for a video?
I tried video.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener()); 
but eclipse is saying that you can instantite MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener

Comment: Hah, nevermind, I got it working now. Thank you very much! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
myVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           //write your code after complete video play  
        }
    });
```