# How to move to another activity after a video is finished?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-videoview

I am trying to increase the delay time if the user went to home screen and return to the app when the video is done. I want the app to move to the next activity. How can i do that?

My current code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
var currentp=0
var tmi:Long=7000
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var inte= Intent(this,Main_menu::class.java)
        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        )
        va.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        val videoview : VideoView = va

        val uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + R.raw.intro)
        videoview.setVideoURI(uri)
        va.setZOrderOnTop(true)
        videoview.start()

        Handler().postDelayed({

    startActivity(inte)},7000)
}
     override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
currentp=va.currentPosition

     }

     override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
if(currentp!=0 && currentp!=100){
    va.seekTo(currentp)
        va.start()}
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727916/ending-an-activity-after-a-video-ends

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ending an activity after a video ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727916/ending-an-activity-after-a-video-ends)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JAVA**

```
videoView.setOnCompletionListener(completionListener);
OnCompletionListener completionListener = new OnCompletionListener(){

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent); 
        }
    };
```

I usally code in Java but I tried to convert it in Kotlin, correct me if there is something wrong.

**KOTLIN**

```
videoView.setOnCompletionListener{

            var intent = Intent(this, MainMenu::class.java)                
            startActivity(intent); 
        }
    };
```

Now you should have everything for getting on the right path. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! although is like that in Kotlin
        videoview.setOnCompletionListener {
            var inte= Intent(this,Main_menu::class.java)

            startActivity(inte)}

        }
any way thank you for helping me out!